# Stop buttons getting focus

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I'm implementing a text formatting toolbar using the following buttons.

https://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox

The problem is that I simply loose the focus on the text inputs being edited when I press these buttons. Is there any way to prevent them stealing the focus?

Answer (score 1):

or you may simply return the focus to your textarea:

```
// detect change event from checkboxes
$('#yourtoolbar').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
    $('#yourtextarea').focus();
});
```

Comment: I have multiple text areas and the button action could be from anyone. I am looking for a simple solution than remembering the last focused text area and then divert my focus. It anyway looses the cursor position even then.

Comment: And what about the blur event attached globally to all such text areas so when the area receives blur event, you will just reapply the focus in a similar way like in the example above?